# CYGWIN - Is it consider a subsystem?

Tags: windows, connection, cygwin, symlink, subsystem

As it stands, I can’t quite understand;

Is Cygwin treated as a windows subsystem, or is it in itself a part of windows as well?

This opens other questions;

If it is, in fact, a subsystem; what do I do to include windows as part of that subsystem or vice versa; make cygwin a part of windows?

How do symlinks come into play?

Are symlinks the way to connect those two?

And do the permission settings also connect when you make cygwin a part of windows or vice versa?

Thank you in advance,

Sincerely
~D.Fairway

Comment: About Symlinks in Cygwin, there are two entries in the [Cygwin FAQ](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html) which you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT a windows subsystem.
Cygwin is a user space POSIX enviroment

Further info on Cygwin Documentation
https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.what.what
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/overview.html#what-is-it